# MySQL Select rows where column contains only values from a set

Tags: mysql, sql, rows

Is there a way to select rows where one of the column contains only predefined values? I've been using this, but it returns any rows where my column contains at least one of the values (which is exactly what it's suppose to do, I know). But I'm looking for a way to only select rows that have ONLY my keywords in the keyword column.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    `products`.`product` 
WHERE 
    keywords LIKE '%chocolate%' 
AND keyword LIKE '%vanilla%';
```

I'm looking for something to do this

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   `products`.`product` 
WHERE 
   keywords **ONLY** LIKE '%chocolate%' 
OR keyword LIKE '%vanilla%';
```

I've tried to make the most sense with this question, hopefully someone has a magic solution for me!

UPDATE/Examples:
Keywords: chocolate, sugar, milk, oats

Using the above keywords, I would want the first two results returned, but not the last two:

Product1: chocolate, sugar
Product2: chocolate
Product3: chocolate, sugar, milk, oats, bran
Product4: chocolate, sugar, salt

My column contains a comma separated list of all keywords applicable to that product row.

Comment: where it is only `chocolate` and not `something chocolate else`, right? match the word exactly?

Comment: Can you please share some sample data? I'm not sure I understand how the `keywords` column looks like.

Comment: An easier way to explain what you want is to give expected results - and show maybe 3 rows - one that would match and two that shouldnt.

Comment: Looks like I should have provided more info, updated with more details. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `products`.`product` WHERE keywords = 'chocolate' OR keyword = 'vanilla';
```

From the information you have given that will do what you want - or is there more to it?

Comment: A bit more I think, Let's say I had 10 keywords, I would want to return a product that contained only keywords in the list, but any number of them. It looks like that's doing about what I have now, which is returning any product that contains at least one of the keywords. Any refinement? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT *
 FROM `products`.`product`
 WHERE (keywords LIKE '%chocolate%' AND keyword NOT LIKE '%vanilla%')
 OR (keywords NOT LIKE '%chocolate%' AND keyword LIKE '%vanilla%');
```

Comment: That's the right idea, but I would be using a keyword list populated at runtime, and it could be quite long. Let's say I had 10 keywords, I would want to return a product that contained only keywords in the list, but any number of them.